# Compare list of tuples - Equals no matter position

Tags: python, list, tuples, comparison

Assuming:

```
a = [(1,2,3),(4,5,6)]
b = [(4,5,6),(1,2,3)]
```

I want the following comparison to be True. Meaning position of tuple inside list doesn't matter.

```
a == b
```

Comment: Sort the lists, then compare them.

Comment: @PatrickHaugh Won't work if there are dupes in one but not the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sort the lists, then compare them:

```
a = [(1,2,3),(4,5,6)]
b = [(4,5,6),(1,2,3)]
sorted(a)==sorted(b)
# True
```

Answer (score 2):

Create a [**multiset**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset) - [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) object in Python - from both lists and compare those:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> a = [(1,2,3), (4,5,6)]
>>> b = [(4,5,6), (1,2,3)]
>>> Counter(a) == Counter(b)
True
```

Comment: Looks like an overkill... Why not just sort the lists?

Comment: What makes you think it's an overkill as compared to O(nlogn) sorting ? You can't tell except you time both.

Comment: Interesting approach - I wonder what the performance of `Counter` is compared to a sort? My gut feeling is that it would be faster...

Comment: @DYZ Correct me if i'm wrong, but building the `Counter` should be `O(n)`, while sorting is `O(nlogn)`

Comment: It runs 15 times slower on this example. Probably because of counter creation overhead.

Comment: @DYZ The speed of sort for a list of tuples depends on how dissimilar the items in the tuples are, which is pretty subjective.

Comment: @MosesKoledoye If the first element is different, then comparison takes time O(1) with respect to the tuple length. On the other hand, hashing for dictionary lookup is always O(N). So, who knows.

Comment: [Here's a REPL](https://repl.it/@Haugh/MidnightblueTightKudu) I threw together to check (using bare ints, not tuples).  As expected, there comes a point where `Counter` pulls ahead in speed, though not by much compared to `sorted`.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about repetitions, use sets: `set(a) == set(b)`

Otherwise, sort them: `sorted(a) == sorted(b)`